# Multiple payment integration using spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, payment-gateway

Is there any library or good way to integrate the multiple payment method using spring boot?

Currently I would like to integrate the a payment gateway s(PayPal, giro pay, klarna, stripe, google pay, credit card and few more) to the e-commerce related web app.

I have to handle all those gateway separately which is hard to handle.